# WPF C# Issue with getting position of passwordBox (x,y)

Tags: c#, wpf, location, screen

Good afternoon,

I need to get location of PasswordBox which is placed somewhere on my form called "LogInWindow.xaml", because I want to simulate psyhical/mouse click on that textBox.

I allready have function which is accepting two parameters, and which is doing click and those parameters are x & y which should be location of target control, here is the function:

```
  public static void LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos)
    {
        SetCursorPos(xpos, ypos);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
    }
```

so what I am missing here is `xpos` and `ypos` (coordinates of target control) and here is one of the ways I tried to get positions but its not working unfortunately:

```
Point relativePoint = txtPassword.TransformToAncestor(Application.Current.MainWindow)
                       .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

I got error on txtPassword that says:
Error   14  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Main.LogInWindow.txtPassword'

I finally made this working by following @FrancisLord advice.

**But now I am facing another issue**, I wanted to test this on another computer/monitor, and I copied my .exe file and I saw that this is not working on another machine, on my developer machine I saw that my function `LeftMouseClick` is working fine because its triggering "button1" that I am looking for, and on another machine looks like its not simulating click, maybe it can't find position of button1 or whatever :// :/// 
Here is my code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        relativePoint = this.button1.TransformToAncestor(this)
                           .Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        LeftMouseClick((int)relativePoint.X, (int)relativePoint.Y);

    //restOFcode
 }
```

Comment: Just a quick question like that : why did you want to simulate a click? is it to set focus on the textbox? if so, I'm sure WPF has a much better way of doing this than simulating a mouse click :)

Comment: Because I am using touch screen, and somehow on newer Operating Systems like W8.1 and W10 its remembers last move I did so whatever I touch it keeps repeating that button(button I presed) and I find out that only way to cancel that is when user log out simulate click somehwere on screen and that would cancel previous action

Comment: That is really weird, never seen anything like that

Comment: Its probably because of monitors drivers, they are working somehow different that drivers of windows XP, code is ok for sure because on xp everything is fine, only on newer OS I had that problem. P.S I did edit on my questions so could you take a look :(

Comment: I am aware you did edits, I just can't help you at all with that. I'm still a Windows Forms guy :) And I have absolutely no idea why your code is not working.

Comment: Its almost the same as wforms and its realy strange that leftbuttonclick is not triggered on another machine and on deverloper it is, I am afraid that is because of monitor types/touch or not touch, but I hope it's not because code is code, it should execute on  touch screen same as on not touch screens

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I still have no idea why it's not working :). I'd be tempted to advise to create a new question with that new problem. In the eyes of most people, this question is closed and done for since you selected an accepted answer. If you want people to see your question, you're probably better off creating a new one with just that problem. Chances are someone else with better knowledge of what you are trying to do will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look by the error that you are trying to assign the value of `relativePoint` through a filed initializer (that is when you set a value to a class level variable in it's declaration), which you cannot do if it calls methods or properties. What you should do here is declare that filed at the class level like right now, but assign it's s value in the constructor of your form's class :

```
public class MyForm : Window
{
    Point relativePoint;

    public MyForm() 
    {
        //other code already in the constructor

        relativePoint = txtPassword.TransformToAncestor(Application.Current.MainWindow)
                   .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    }
}
```

PS: sorry if the class name or inheritance don't make sense, I don't know what it's supposed to look like for WPF

Comment: This helped me, but now when I run app I am facing error : The specified Visual is not ancestor of Visual. at System.Windows.Media.Visual.TrySimpleTransform... etc..hmmm

Comment: I have find issue, in rootVisual i did not passed expecting window, so now it is allright I think but I will test in a second.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you much with that, those are errors from WPF, and I never worked with WPF.

Comment: Acctualy this helped me to get location of my control! thanks mate :)  I did edit to my question, could you guys take a look

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to get position from window

```
Point locationFromWindow = txtPassword.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), Application.Current.MainWindow);
```

add this line to get position from screen

```
Point locationFromScreen = txtPassword.PointToScreen(locationFromWindow);
```